# MySQL help: Find Rank of a particular user on the number of its occurance in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables 'users' and 'invites'

Fields of users - id, name, email, ...

Fields of invites- email, invitedby, status

My Problems:

1. Find the **rank list** of users on 'invites' table where the top user will be the one who has the most number of (status='confirmed') invites.
2. Find the rank of a particular user say id=15 where it stands on the **rank list** of total umber of invites.

Tones of Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For the first,

```
SELECT invitedby as id,COUNT(*) as confirmed
FROM invites
WHERE status='confirmed'
GROUP BY invitedby
```

For the second, use the first as a subquery (or you could make a view out of it) and then check to see how many other ids have a greater value than the one for the user you're looking for:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as rank FROM (
    SELECT invitedby as id,COUNT(*) as confirmed
    FROM invites
    WHERE status='confirmed'
    GROUP BY invitedby
) as s
WHERE s.confirmed > XXXXX
```

(and replace XXXXX with the confirm count of the user you're querying for - if you make the first query a view you can easily use another SELECT to look this up). This will give you a rank where the top item is 0, the second item is 1, and so on.

Comment: Thnx a lot Amber, i modified the WHERE clause at the last of the 2nd query with id=xxx to get the rank of that particular id.

Comment: Um, that may not actually do what you want. The `>` comparison for the values is important if you actually want to get position within the rank list.

Comment: Then how do I get the rank of a particular user using its user id? Also I want to find the users next/previous rank. Suppose user id=15 is in 5th rank how will I find the 4th and 6th rank?
Thnx